# Facebook login in flutter not working hash key

Tags: flutter, facebook

[image]

showing this error on facebook console
Error found while validating app-ads.txt. com.abc.appname We couldn't find your developer website URL in your app's store listing. Learn more

my code working on emulator correctly but not working on real device
i already add hash generated by flutter

```
keytool -exportcert -alias releasebuild -keystore H:/dart/Office/project/android/app/uploadkeystore.jks | C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe  sha1 -binary | C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe base64
```

but it make hash key of 28 character but no ending with = sign

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that **releasebuild** is your allias name, see following command line for generate key for facebook Login.

keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

[more details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android)